# Style a document.write javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi I am looking to style the following document.write script so that the Business Goal: is in red and the (BusinessName) will be displayed in black.

document.write("Business Name: ",  unescape(BusinessName));

I assume it is something like this:

h3 style="color:#333

Any help would be appreciated    - for some reason it wont allow me to enter tags on this forum

Comment: Yep, something like that. Make sure you also close the `h3` element and watch the quotes you are using.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: Use the code button or back ticks if you want to insert/edit code into your post.

Comment: Find the parent element that you want to contain your HTML ([`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)) and append HTML with something like [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: Or better yet use a library like jQuery to make this work much easier.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Use `document.write` if it's the best tool for the job. But for a lot of jobs, it isn't. Using `document.write` is *discouraged*. It's not deprecated, and it's not underspecified. It's just easy to go wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document.write you can use innerHTML. You can see an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)